# Disclosure triangle is not appearing on my UITableViewCell

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview

How can I have a label on a UITableViewCell but also have an arrow on the very right side of it?

This is what I tried:

```
   } else if(indexPath.row == 1) {
        UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(50,0,200,21)];
        label.text = @"Select to change code";
        label.tag = 1;
        label.textColor = [UIColor grayColor];
        cell.accessoryView = label;
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
    }
```

But it's not working. I see the label but I do not see the arrow on the very right side of the cell.

Comment: I want to advise you that the title of your question may be incorrect...

Comment: @DreamOfMirrors - not anymore it isn't.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the following :

```
 else if(indexPath.row == 1) {
    UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(50,0,200,21)];
    label.text = @"Select to change code";
    label.tag = 1;
    label.textColor = [UIColor grayColor];
    [cell addSubview:label];//i changed oonly this line 
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
}
```

Hope it helps you........

Edit: (because I can not comment. The reason for the small change is in your original code you had added the label to the cell as it's accessoryType subView (effectively covering it with your label) whereas in the revised code, the label was correctly added as a separate subview to the cell.

Comment: That should be [cell.contentView addSubview] - don't add stuff to the cell directly. Also this will simply overlap the default title and / or image views if they are used.

Answer (score 0):

You can't have both a custom accessory view and the system supplied view that you get with cell.accessoryType. How about this:

```
cell.textLabel.text =  @"Select to change code";
cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
```